# Calculate interquartile mean from Ruby array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, math, statistics

I have this array:

```
[288.563044, 329.835918, 578.622569, 712.359026, 866.614253, 890.066321, 1049.78037, 1070.29897, 2185.443662, 2492.245562, 4398.300227, 13953.264379]
```

How do I calculate the [interquartile mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_mean#Examples) from this?

That Wikipedia link explains it best, but I basically need to remove the bottom and top 25% leaving only the middle 50%, of which I'll need to average the numbers.

But that's assuming the number of array items is divisible by 4. [Here's how to calculate it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_mean#Dataset_not_divisible_by_four) when it's not divisible by four.

So how would I do that as well?

Comment: What specifically are you having an issue with? The linked article explains the algorithm.

Comment: How to actually implement that with Ruby.

Comment: The array. :) Not sure how to remove top 25% and bottom 25%, or really even get started on the one not divisible by 4.

Comment: You can take a chunk of an array using `arr[n1..n2]`, so in the case of 12 entries, `arr[3..-4]`. Calculating `n1` and `n2` should be pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a partial solution for an array with a number of elements that is a multiple of 4. I'll put the full one when I figure it out.

```
arr = [288.563044, 329.835918, 578.622569, 712.359026, 866.614253, 890.066321, 1049.78037,    1070.29897, 2185.443662, 2492.245562, 4398.300227, 13953.264379].sort!
length = arr.size
mean = arr.sort[(length/4)..-(length/4+1)].inject(:+)/(length/2)
```

I think this is a better solution.

```
def interquartile_mean(array)
   arr = array.sort
   length = arr.size
   quart = (length/4.0).floor
   fraction = 1-((length/4.0)-quart)
   new_arr = arr[quart..-(quart + 1)]
   (fraction*(new_arr[0]+new_arr[-1]) + new_arr[1..-2].inject(:+))/(length/2.0)
end
```

Comment: No need for the bang on `sort` here since you're operating on the modified array and returning a result, all without using the array again. Also, just pointing out for future reference, `Array#length` and `Array#size` (aliases) are faster than `count`. :)

Comment: I'm not sure I'd `sort!` an array that doesn't belong to the method, though. I'll +1 anyway, although this question has disappointed me on two levels.

Comment: Good thinking, I'll fix that.

Answer (score 2):

The simple case `array_size mod 4 = 0`:

```
xs = [5, 8, 4, 38, 8, 6, 9, 7, 7, 3, 1, 6]
q = xs.size / 4
ys = xs.sort[q...3*q]
mean = ys.inject(0, :+) / ys.size.to_f
#=> 6.5
```

The general case (`array_size >= 4`):

```
xs = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17]
q = xs.size / 4.0
ys = xs.sort[q.ceil-1..(3*q).floor]
factor = q - (ys.size/2.0 - 1)
mean = (ys[1...-1].inject(0, :+) + (ys[0] + ys[-1]) * factor) / (2*q)
#=> 9.0
```

However, if you don't try to code it yourself this won't help much...

Answer (score 1):

An improvement on tokland's answer that augments the Array class and fixes an edge case (method as written blows up with array size of 4).

```
class Array
  def interquartile_mean
     a = sort
     l = size
     quart = (l.to_f / 4).floor
     t = a[quart..-(quart + 1)]
     t.inject{ |s, e| s + e }.to_f / t.size
  end
end
```